# Submit button adds comment

Tags: python, angular, flask

I want my submit button to add the comment fields into the comment section. I am trying to do this with Angular. Currently using Python and Flask to handle the backend side. How would I go about starting this?
[Link to Screenshot of Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0BtJ.png)

app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/blog')
def blogpost():
    return render_template('blogpost.html')
```

html for blog page

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head_content %}
<title>Blog</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/blogpost.css') }} ">
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}

<div class="blog_post">
    <div class="author_info">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/default_profile_picture.png') }}">
        <ul>
            <li id="name">Justin York</li>
            <li id="email">Justin120197@gmail.com</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="post"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Porttitor massa id neque aliquam. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo. Purus in massa tempor nec. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. In fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id.</p>

        <p>Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis. Quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat. Ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id.</p>
            
        <p>Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum. Donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non. Sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam. Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis. Dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam at.</p>
            
        <p>Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque. Quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin.</p>
            
        <p>Sit amet risus nullam eget. Maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. At lectus urna duis convallis. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus. Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="comment_section">
        <h2>Comments</h2>
        <div class="comments">
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="comment">
                <h3>Commenter Name</h3>
                <h5>Commenter@Email.com</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.</p>
            </div>
            <hr />
            
            
        </div>

        <div class='submit_comment'>
            <form id='comment_form'>
                <label for='name'>Name:</label>
                <input id='name' type="text" name='name'>

                <label for='email'>Email:</label>
                <input id='email' type='email' name='email'>

                <label for='comment_body'>Comment:</label>
                <textarea id='comment_body' type="text" name='email' rows=8 cols=100></textarea>

                <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I set up an Angular script to do this, or what shold I do instead?

Comment: Unless this is just an exercise in changing frontend state, you need a back end data store for the comments.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Find a database that fits your needs, then start reading - mongodb, MariaDB, or a cloud system. Some particularly scrappy devs have used google sheets.